# map annotation with different marker using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am working in map view annotation.
The marker annotation should be displayed using the parking rule type
If paid pin image be "paid" and if free pin image be "free"
I am getting all annotation as "paid" image

I have attached my code below can any one help me in this issue to fix

[image]

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Better to make this class property
    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
        // Configure your annotation view here
        if parkingTypeArray.count > 0 {


            for cameraa in parkingTypeArray.enumerated() {

                if cameraa.element == "Free street parking" {

                    let pinImage = UIImage(named: "free")
                    annotationView.image = pinImage

                }else if cameraa.element == "Paid street parking" {

                    let pinImage = UIImage(named: "paid")
                    annotationView.image = pinImage

                }else if cameraa.element == "Paid parking" {

                    let pinImage = UIImage(named: "paid")
                    annotationView.image = pinImage
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: because of for loop of "camerra". your last element will be "Paid street parking", so that it set all images to paid.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati So will it take only the last element? How to fix this issue

Comment: Please show more context for this code. What kind of class is `cameraa`?

Comment: @KosukeOgawa parkingTypeArray has three values such as "Free street parking", "Paid street parking", "Paid parking". If free pin image should be displayed as free image marker and if paid means image should be displayed as free image marker. And cameraa is fo loop

Comment: Recently I answered similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889111/how-to-show-different-places-icon-on-the-map-view-in-swift-4/51889815#51889815

Comment: As @KosukeOgawa you need to use Customannotaion class to get image name to be set for annotation

Answer (score 1):

**Same thing I Have Done with Custom** `MKPointAnnotation` **Class**

```
class MyPointAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
   var obj : ComparableData?

    init(data_obj : ComparableData) {
        self.obj = data_obj
        super.init()
    }
}
```

**Setup Map**

```
for item in self.Arr_Map_Comparables{

    if item.Latitude != "" && item.Longitude != ""{
        let annotation = MyPointAnnotation(data_obj: item)
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(item.Latitude!)!, longitude: Double(item.Longitude!)!)
        annotation.title = item.Full_Address
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

}    
self.focusMarkers(markers: mapView.annotations, width: 50)
```

**MapView Delegate Methods**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
    // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Better to make this class property
    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
        // Configure your annotation view here
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true

        if let annotation = annotationView.annotation as? MyPointAnnotation{

            if annotation.obj?.Status_Mls == "Active"{

                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "active")

            }else if annotation.obj?.Status_Mls == "Sold"{

                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "sold")

            }else{
                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "other")
            }
        }
    }
    return annotationView
}
```