# swift customer map icon in mapkit

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have built an app that has a split view: a table and a map. I want to change the marker image according to the type of animal. I add the code below but the marker hasn't changed.

**LocationListController.swift**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Animal")
    do{
        animalList = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Animal]

    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Failded to fetch teams: \(error)")
    }
    let location: FencedAnnotation = FencedAnnotation (newTitle: "*****", newSubtitle: "*****", lat: -33, long: 145.045374, newType: "Start", newPhoto: "none")
    filteredList = animalList
    for animal in filteredList{
        let annotation = FencedAnnotation(newTitle: animal.name!, newSubtitle: animal.animaldescription!, lat: animal.latitude, long: animal.longtitude, newType: animal.type!, newPhoto: animal.photo!)
        self.locationList.add(annotation)
        self.mapViewController?.addAnnotation(annotation: annotation)
    }

    geoLocation = CLCircularRegion(center: location.coordinate, radius: 500, identifier: location.title!)
    geoLocation!.notifyOnExit = true
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: geoLocation!)

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Animal"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    tableView.reloadData()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}
```

**mapView.swift**

```
func addAnnotation(annotation: FencedAnnotation) {
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}


func removeAnnotation(annotation: FencedAnnotation)  {
    self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
}

func focusOn(annotation: MKAnnotation)   {
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate
    self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated:true)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    let customPointAnnotation = annotation as! FencedAnnotation
    if customPointAnnotation.type == "cat"{
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cat")
    }
    if customPointAnnotation.type == "dog"{
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dog")
    }
    if customPointAnnotation.type == "fish"{
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fish")
    }
    if customPointAnnotation.type == "monkey"{
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "monkey")
    }
    if customPointAnnotation.type == "fish"{
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bird")
    }
    if customPointAnnotation.type == "fish"{
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mouse")
    }
    else{
        annotationView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder")
    }
    annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    return annotationView
}
```

I fetch the list from core data and use a customer MKAnnotation to add the annotation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [mcve] and update your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Try `for animal in filteredList { print(animal.type)`

Comment: **Here is Working code for set map annotation with a different marker images according to type try it.** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51945906/10150796